# Where is the "staging directory" on Elastic Beanstalk instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to locate the **staging directory** as mentioned in the Elastic Beanstalk documentation.

> The specified commands run as the root user, and are processed in alphabetical order by name. Container commands are run from the staging directory, where your source code is extracted prior to being deployed to the application server. Any changes you make to your source code in the staging directory with a container command will be included when the source is deployed to its final location.

Comment: It will already be the working directory for any commands run in the deploy scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The staging directory is in **/var/app/ondeck**. Or at least this is the case on their managed platform **Puma with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.11.0**.

To check your own SSH into your Beanstalk instance and do:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
```

You can also create a script in **.ebextensions/** and issue a command that will be something like:

```
echo "We are here: $(pwd)"
```

You'll then be able to check **eb-activity.log** for that line.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who ends up here, this worked for me:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config platformconfig -k AppStagingDir
```

Amazon's documentation actually provides that exact command on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html) (you have to expand the `platformconfig – Constant configuration values` section to see it).